# Plotting pandas dataframe after doing pandas melt is slow and creates strange y-axis

Tags: python, pandas, plotnine

This could be caused by me not understanding how [`pandas.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.melt.html) works but I get strange behaviour when plotting "melted" dataframes using [plotnine](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine). Both frames has been converted from wide to long format. One frame with a column containing string values (`df_slow`) and another with only numerical values (`df_fast`).

The following code gives different behaviour. Plotting `df_slow` is slow and gives a strange looking y-axis. Plotting `df_fast` looks ok and is fast. My guess is that pandas melt is doing something strange with the data which causes this behaviour. See example plots.

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotnine as p9

SIZE = 200
value = np.random.rand(SIZE, 1)

# Create test data, one with a column containing strings, one with only numeric values
df_slow = pd.DataFrame({'value': value.flatten(), 'string_column': ['A']*SIZE})
df_fast = pd.DataFrame({'value': value.flatten()})

# Set index
df_slow = df_slow.reset_index()
df_fast = df_fast.reset_index()

# Convert 'df_slow', 'df_fast' to long format
df_slow = pd.melt(df_slow, id_vars='index')
df_fast = pd.melt(df_fast, id_vars='index')

print(df_slow.head())
print(df_fast.head())
df_slow = df_slow[df_slow.variable == 'value']

# This is slow and has many breaks on y-axis
p = (p9.ggplot(df_slow, p9.aes(x='index', y='value')) + p9.geom_point())
p.draw()

# This is much faster and y-axis looks good
p = (p9.ggplot(df_fast, p9.aes(x='index', y='value')) + p9.geom_point())
p.draw()
```

[slow and strange plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kLFK.png)

[fast and good looking plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrDPO.png)

### Possible fix

Changing the type of  the "value" column in `df_slow` makes it behave like `df_fast` when plotting.

```python
# This makes df_slow behave like df_fast when plotting
df_slow['value'] = df_slow.value.astype(np.float64)
```

### Question

Is this a bug in [plotnine](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine) (or [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/index.html)) or am I doing something wrong?

### Answer

When pivoting two columns with different data types, in this case string and float, I guess it makes sense that the resulting column containing both strings and floats will have the type object. As 
ALollz pointed out this probably makes plotnine interpret the values as strings which causes this behavior.

Comment: Take a look at `df_slow.dtypes` and `df_fast.dtypes`. You'll see the difference is that the `'value'` column is an object for `df_slow`. So when it's trying to plot, it must be interpreting them as strings and so the y-axis gets ruined because it plots the label for every single value.

Comment: Also, `DataFrame.plot` seems to get it correct without issue. Try `df_slow.plot(x='index', y='value', marker='o', lw=0)`

Comment: Well spotted. You are right. The types differ. I didn't expect `pandas.melt` to change the datatype. I only checked `type(df_slow['value'][0])` which gives float. This is a boiled down test because this happened when I was plotting something similar using plotnine and melted data frames.